# How can I update a dictionary so that if key 'a' has a value of 'c' than the key of 'c' appends the value 'a'?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key-value

If key `'a'` has a value of `'c'` then the key of `'c'` should append `'a'`. Please note that that the values associated with key `'a'` are not included in the append.

I cant seem to figure out how to automate this process to perform on a large dictionary.

```
mydict = {
'a': ['z', 'c'],
'b': ['y', 'c'],
'c': ['q', 'r']
}
```

Here is my desired result :

```
mydict = {
'a': ['z', 'c'],
'b': ['y', 'c'],
'c': ['q', 'r', 'a', 'b']
}
```

Comment: Not the values but you are appending the keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way to do this, using set intersections, as well as keeping an intermediate mapping of parent/children relationships.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

keys = set([*mydict])

for k, v in mydict.items():
    intersected = keys & set(v)
    for i in intersected:
        d[i].append(k)

print(d)
# defaultdict(list, {'c': ['b', 'a']})

for found, value in d.items():
    mydict[found].extend(value)

print(mydict)
# {'a': ['z', 'c'], 'b': ['y', 'c'], 'c': ['q', 'r', 'b', 'a']}
```

Comment: Why `set([*mydict])` instead of `set(mydict)`?

Comment: didn't realize that would just give the keys as well

Answer (score -1):

```
for k in mydict:
    for val in mydict[k]:
        if val in mydict:
            mydict[val] += [k]
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it